# Pass template parts via API

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to have the same header and footer as my WordPress site on another site (that doesn't use WordPress) with a different domain and hosting. The manager of the other site wants it via API but I've never done it and I'm not very expert. You need to have the same header and footer (including the style) so you don't have to manually change it every time a link in the menu changes. I know a little bit of PHP, I made the WordPress site theme myself, but I haven't dealt with this kind of thing yet.

This is the code I'm using on my WordPress Functions.php site:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'top-section/v1', '/header', [
        'method'   => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'return_header',
    ] );
} );
function return_header( $request ) {
    $response = get_header();
    return rest_ensure_response( $response );
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function() {
    register_rest_route( 'bottom-section/v1', '/footer', [
        'method'   => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'return_footer',
    ] );
} );
function return_footer( $request ) {
    $response = get_footer();
    return rest_ensure_response( $response );
}
```

and I call it like this in an index.html file in another domain to do some tests:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Non WordPress Site</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="header-container"></div>

    <script>
        // Funzione per ottenere le informazioni dell'header
        function getWordPressHeader() {
            fetch('https://example.com/wp-json/top-section/v1/header')
                .then(response => response.text())  // Puoi anche usare .json() se la risposta è JSON
                .then(data => {
                    // Aggiungi il codice dell'header al tuo sito non WordPress
                    document.getElementById('header-container').innerHTML = data;
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching WordPress header:', error));
        }

        // Chiama la funzione per ottenere le informazioni dell'header
        getWordPressHeader();
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

This code "works" in the sense that it transmits the header and footer but there are several problems:

1. the search bar doesn't work on the copy site (the non-WordPress one)
2. using `get_header()` I get all the contents of header.php which also contains the `<head>` tags useful for providing the style but perhaps it would be better to separate them? so as to have header and head separated
3. header.php obviously like all themes does not only contain static html but also PHP (e.g. `wp_head(); body_class(); get_template_part(); ...`), which I don't see in the endpoint but I see it executed when I'll call him back. Is this a security issue?
4. using the code I wrote, what can those who use it do? I'm very interested in the security part so I wouldn't want him to be able to access or modify anything
5. How can it be improved? Is it recommended to use JSON in this case?

Sorry for my ignorance but it's the first time I've used it and also the first on Stack. I hope you can help me because I'm not sure how to do it otherwise.